# Jquery .click() with an unanonymus method issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm following and modifing a tutorial in hope to create an interactive skilltree sheet

```
var main = function() {
    var points = parseInt($('.resume').text());
    var pointExpended = 0; 


    $('.node').click(function() {
        var cost = parseInt($(this).children('.info').children('.cost').text());
        if($(this).hasClass('active-node')) {
            //l'abilità viene rimossa 
            $(this).removeClass('active-node');
            pointExpended = pointExpended - cost;
            $('.resume').text(points-pointExpended);
        }
        else {
            //l'abilità viene comprata
            if(points-(pointExpended+cost) < 0) {
                alert("Limite dei punti superato");
            }
            else {
            $(this).addClass('active-node');
            pointExpended = pointExpended + cost;
            $('.resume').text(points-pointExpended);
            }
        }
    });
   };


   $(document).ready(main);
```

to add some recursion i'm trying to put the handler into an external function

```
var click_handler = function() {

        alert(points);

        var cost = parseInt($(this).children('.info').children('.cost').text());
        if($(this).hasClass('active-node')) {
            //l'abilità viene rimossa 
            $(this).removeClass('active-node');
            pointExpended = pointExpended - cost;
            $('.resume').text(points-pointExpended);
        }
        else {
            //l'abilità viene comprata
            if(points-(pointExpended+cost) < 0) {
                alert("Limite dei punti superato");
            }
            else {
            $(this).addClass('active-node');
            pointExpended = pointExpended + cost;
            $('.resume').text(points-pointExpended);
            }
        }
    }

var main = function() {
    var points = parseInt($('.resume').text());
    var pointExpended = 0; 

    alert(points);

    $('.node').click(click_handler);
};


$(document).ready(main);
```

but the code does not respond to the clicks.

I'm pretty new to jscript/jquery so i can't figure why the first try works and not the latter

Comment: try to put var points = parseInt($('.resume').text());
    var pointExpended = 0;  in the click_handler function not in main function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

variable `points` and `pointEtended` are not visible to your click handler (variable scope is a lexical stuff, and does not work on the call stack..) so you need to pass them in with a closure:

```
var main = function() {
    var points = parseInt($('.resume').text());
    var pointExpended = 0; 

    alert(points);

    $('.node').click(function(evt) {
              click_handler(evt, points, pointExtended)
    });
};
```

also modify you click_handler to accept named values

```
click_handler(evt, points, pointExtend) { ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've fixed in a little bit uglyer way than you suggested and made points and pointExpended as global and calling click_handler(evt,$(this))

Comment: nice1... beware the global space though - but I guess you are already aware what a minefield that is